# What exactly does "parlant de tout et de rien" mean?

Tags: sens, traduction

Example:

> —Tu exagères mon ami, car même si tu n’aimes pas la grammaire, tu sais bien que c’est important.
>   —Pfff ! je sais que tu as raison, mais c’est difficile de l’admettre.
>   —Écoute je te promets que nous allons seulement donner quelques exemples de négation tout en **parlant de tout et de rien**.

How exactly would you translate that into English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Parler de tout et de rien*** (talking about everything and nothing) is an idiom that means to chat about various unrelated sort of things of no particular importance. I have seen ***talking about this and that*** but have no idea about if it is an "exact translation" (if such thing exist).

In any case, English idioms should better be asked for in the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: Yeah. I thought that it was an idiom. Thank you.